# Move CSV file to another folder in java

Tags: java

MoveFiles
moveCSV.moveToNewFolder(source,destination); -  This method always returns false for this file "REPORT_AUDIT_LOGGING_REPORT_20140102.csv".
if I create any dummy CSV file,
it is moved as expected.
Can someone please help me to understand whats happening with this file?

```
String csvFilename =
    "C:\\Data\\csv_files\\REPORT_AUDIT_LOGGING_REPORT_20140102.csv";
String  OutputfileName = "GISWREPTPD_Output" + getDateTime()+ ".csv";
File outputfile = new File ("C:\\Data\\Output", OutputfileName );

CSVWriter write = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputfile));
CSVReader csvR = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'', 1);

File source = new File ("C:\\Data\\csv_files");
File destination = new File ("C:\\Data\\Archive");

------
------

write.close();

MoveFiles moveCSV = new MoveFiles();
moveCSV.moveToNewFolder(source,destination);


MoveFiles.java
===============
public void moveToNewFolder(File source, File destination) throws IOException 
{
for (File files : source.listFiles())
{
System.out.println("File Name:"files);
System.out.println("Renamed:" +
    files.renameTo(new File (destination, files.getName())));   

}
}

Result:
File Name:C:\Data\csv_files\GISWREPTPD_AUDIT_LOGGING_REPORT_20140102.csv
Renamed:false
```

Comment: Do you have permissions for the file?

Comment: Do you need a `csvR.close()` ?

Comment: show how you are setting the value `renamed`

Comment: I have permissions and I used csvR.close(). It worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I spent a lot of time to debug this but no luck

Comment: File.renameTo is quirky and platform dependent: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)  I've seen it fail if writing across volumes, for e.g.  Suggest you use something like Apache commons FileUtils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File, java.io.File)

Comment: Or use the JDK7 `Files.move` API.

Comment: Even if you can't stick with JDK7 for some operational reason, you may try it just to get a better error message from the JVM as to the failure you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example. I found this example in a book. you can easily play with this code to meet your needs.

```
public class FileCopier {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            File inboxDirectory = new File("data/inbox");
            File outboxDirectory = new File("data/outbox");
            outboxDirectory.mkdir();
            File[] files = inboxDirectory.listFiles();
            for (File source : files) {
                if (source.isFile()) {
                    File dest = new File(outboxDirectory.getPath()+ File.separator+ source.getName());
                    copyFIle(source, dest);
                }
            }
        }
        private static void copyFile(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) source.length()];
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
            in.read(buffer);
            try {
              out.write(buffer);
            } finally {
              out.close();
              in.close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That works but the Apache Commons util I indicated above will use java.nio and be measurably faster.